# How can I get background color of a selected item in checkboxlist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, styles, checkboxlist

I am using a checkboxlist to bind some data from database. Each item in checkboxlist is set with a unique background color. I need to get the background color set to a selected item in the checkboxlist. For binding the colors I have used the code below

```
for (int i = 0; i < cbFilter.Items.Count; i++)    
{
Color RandomColor = GetRandomColor();
string hexColorValue = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(RandomColor);
cbFilter.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:" + hexColorValue);
}
```

Please give a solution to fetch the background color of a selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            foreach (ListItem  item in cbFilter.Items   )
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    Response.Write(item.Attributes.CssStyle["background-color"].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but I am getting the error     Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user.net:please provide complete code so that i can provide proper solution